# How to pass single List Items from one Activity to another and how to adapt them to the Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

In my MainActivity I have got a `RecyclerView` which is Inflated by an `ArrayList<>` that I have also in my `MainActivity`.

When I tap on an Item in the `RecyclerView` I would like to open another Activity that is Inflated by the same Strings and Images I was using in the `RecyclerView` plus some more Images that have to be put in a PagerView.

The questions are the following:

- **How can I pass a single ListItem to another Activity?**
- **How do I create an Adapter to inflate both the PagerView and the TextViews?**
- **Is the one I'm suggesting a good enough way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve, or Is there a simplier, more efficient way to do it?**

I really appreciate any help you could give me, I know it probably isn't easy to understand what I would like to do but please if something is not clear, don't hesitate to ask.

**EDIT:**

This is how my `ArrayList` looks like:

```
chords = new ArrayList<Accordo>(); 
chords.add(new Accordo(R.drawable.do_maggiore, R.drawable.do_maggiore2, R.drawable.do_maggiore3, "Do maggiore", "Do, Mi, Sol")); 
chords.add(new Accordo(R.drawable.do5, R.drawable.do5_2, R.drawable.do5_3, "Do 5", "Na, na, na")); 
chords.add(new Accordo(R.drawable.do6, R.drawable.do6_2, R.drawable.do6_3, "Do 6", "Note: na, na, na")); 
chords.add(new Accordo(R.drawable.do7, R.drawable.do7_2, R.drawable.do7_3, "do 7", "Note: na, na, na"));
//more items
```

**EDIT 2**

this is the xml I need to create the Adapter for:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/parte_sopra"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/accordo_view_nome" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:textAllCaps="true" 
     android:layout_marginStart="10dp" 
     android:textSize="25sp" 
     android:text="TEXTVIEW" 
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
     android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" 
     android:textStyle="bold" 
     android:textColor="@color/black" /> 

  <TextView android:id="@+id/accordo_view_note" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" 
     android:text="TEXTVIEW" 
     android:textSize="24sp" 
     android:layout_marginTop="12dp" 
     android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" 
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/> 

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
   android:id="@+id/pager" 
   android:layout_height="250dp" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_marginStart="10dp" 
   android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

What kind of Adapter should I use?
`PagerAdapter` even though I have two `TextViews` outside the `PagerView`?

Comment: then you need to make Accordo class Implement Serializable

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF I have already done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Parcelable to pass the data between Activity.

Example:
Set data after click on item (in first activity)

```
intent.putExtra("DATA_ID", MY_DATA);
```

Get data (secound activity)

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
MY_DATA myData = (MY_DATA) data.getParcelable("DATA_ID");
```

More here: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

You can also use Serializable. Serializable is easier to implement but is slower so I recommend Parcelable

How do I create an Adapter to inflate both the PagerView and the TextViews? - more details please

Comment: Thank you for the answer what details do you need? Should I post the xml?

Comment: Please check out the question I have added the xml

Answer (score 0):

When the user click on an item you should be able to get what Item has been clicked on.

You need to make your list items implements Serializable. Then when you launch the next activity you can put an extra in the intent.

```
intent.putExtra("selected", obj);
```

To retrieve what you have passed you can use this.

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selected");
```

For populating the ViewPager where does the extra images come from ? It should not be a problem to use the approach you are describing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer the extra Images are coming from the ListItem they aren't used in the RecyclerView though